# Rotating a cube through an arbitrary axis and deconvolving it back to the original x,y and z axes in matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d, matlab-figure

I have an application where I have to rotate a cube about an arbitrary axis by an angle theta using Matlab. I am using [Rodrigues rotation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) to achieve this. Note that I am only interested in rotation about the cube's center, thus the axis I specify will pass through the center.

The following is my code which does this:

```
%cube rotation
xc=0; yc=0; zc=0;    % coordinates of the center
L=1;                 % cube size (length of an edge)
alpha=0.2;
% transparency (max=1=opaque)

Xmag=1;%specify the axis vector and the angle to rotate by
Ymag=1;
Zmag=1;
angle=30;

X = [0 0 0 0 0 1; 1 0 1 1 1 1; 1 0 1 1 1 1; 0 0 0 0 0 1];% define the cube coordinates
Y = [0 0 0 0 1 0; 0 1 0 0 1 1; 0 1 1 1 1 1; 0 0 1 1 1 0];
Z = [0 0 1 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0 0 0; 1 1 1 0 1 1; 1 1 1 0 1 1];                                              
C=  [0.5 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1];

X = L*(X-0.5) + xc;% translate cube so that its center is at the origin
Y = L*(Y-0.5) + yc;
Z = L*(Z-0.5) + zc;


mag=sqrt(Xmag*Xmag+Ymag*Ymag+Zmag*Zmag);%find the unit vector correspoding to the axis vector
x=Xmag/mag;
y=Ymag/mag;
z=Zmag/mag;

th=0;

for count=1:0.01:angle
cla;
if(th<angle)
     th=th+0.01;
end 

c=cos(th); %rodrigues formula
s=sin(th);
t=1-cos(th);

for i=1:1:4
    for j=1:1:6
        Xnew_th(i,j)=X(i,j)*(t*x*x+c)+Y(i,j)*(t*x*y-s*z)+Z(i,j)*(t*x*y+s*y);
        Ynew_th(i,j)=X(i,j)*(t*x*y+s*z)+Y(i,j)*(t*y*y+c)+Z(i,j)*(t*y*z-s*x);
        Znew_th(i,j)=X(i,j)*(t*x*z-s*y)+Y(i,j)*(t*y*z+s*x)+Z(i,j)*(t*z*z+c);
    end 
end 

fill3(Xnew_th,Ynew_th,Znew_th,C,'FaceAlpha',alpha); % draw cube
axis([-1 1 -1 1 -1 1]);
xlabel('X Axis');
ylabel('Y Axis');
zlabel('Z Axis');
%grid on;
view(3);% orientation of the axes
pause(0.02);
end
```

**Now, I need to deconvolve this rotation about an arbitrary axis to the angles about the `x-axis`, the `y-axis` and the `z-axis`. That is, I need to find the angles the cube must turn about the `x`, `y` and `z` axes to achieve the same final state that it did using Rodrigues formula.**

**Any ideas on how to do this? Or, is there any other formula instead of Rodrigues formula that takes into account the angles of rotation about the x,y and z axes in constructing the rotation matrix?**

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a thought: [Geometric derivation of Euler angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angle#Geometric_derivation)

Comment: @Schorsch:Could you kindly make that a bit clearer? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) There is an infinite amount of rotations in 3D to get from one orientation to another.
2.) One approach to overcome this, would be to agree on a standard set of angles, for example [Euler angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angle).
3.) How to find Euler angles is described - for example - [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angle#Geometric_derivation).
4.) Given that your cube may be already rotated with regard to `x`, `y`, `z` you should consider computing the angles twice: once for the initial position, once for the resulting position. The delta in angles will be what you are looking for.

**Edit**
From the Wikipedia entry on Euler angles:

> It is interesting to note that the inverse cosine function yields two possible values for the argument. In this geometrical description only one of the solutions is valid. When Euler Angles are defined as a sequence of rotations all the solutions can be valid, but there will be only one inside the angle ranges. This is because the sequence of rotations to reach the target frame is not unique if the ranges are not previously defined.

Which is explained in more detail in [this article](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~sbbh653/publications/euler.pdf).

Comment: I ran into another problem today. Now, if I solve the Rotation matrix for Euler angles, I get multiple sets of solutions. How do I know what solution to pick among them?

Comment: @AnanthSaran : See my edit. You have to consider the ranges of the angles.